# How to pass multiple values from user and search them in a dictionary to return the key

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
sales = {
    "January": 15000, "February": 22000, "March": 12000,
    "April": 17000, "May": 81000, "June": 13000,
    "July": 21000, "August": 41200, "September": 25000,
    "October": 21500, "November": 91000, "December": 21000
}
```

I want for the user to be able to enter as many values as he or she wants, and then print the key or keys depending on the entered value, if the value is not in the dictionary it has to return "not found".

I have tried using this:

```
search = int(sys.argv[1])
sales_inv = {v: k for k, v in sales.items()}
if search in sales.values():
    for key, value in sales.items():
        if search == value:
            print(key)
else:
    print("not found")
```

But when I print, it would only search one value, if i want to search for example: 17000 and 13000, it would only return "April".

Answer (score 1):

I think to get multiple arguments, you can iterate through `sys.argv` starting from index 1 instead just getting `sys.argv[1]` which will only give the second argument value

```
import sys

sales = {
"January": 15000, "February": 22000, "March": 12000, "April": 17000, "May": 81000, "June": 13000, "July": 21000, "August": 41200,"September": 25000, "October": 21500, "November": 91000, "December": 21000}
sales_inv = {v: k for k, v in sales.items()}

for search in sys.argv[1:]:
    search = int(search)
    if search in sales.values():
        for key, value in sales.items():
            if search == value:
                print(key)
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I'm new learning python! :) this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)'s [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) for this. It offers a lot of flexibility out of the box, e.g., the `add_arguments()`'s [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) argument, which allows to automatically gather arguments passed to the program into a list.

Here's how I would do it:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

SALES = {
    "January": 15000,
    "February": 22000,
    "March": 12000,
    "April": 17000,
    "May": 81000,
    "June": 13000,
    "July": 21000,
    "August": 41200,
    "September": 25000,
    "October": 21500,
    "November": 91000,
    "December": 21000,
}

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "sales_numbers",

    # Used in help messages.
    metavar="SALES_NUMBER",

    # Convert the input to integer,
    # print an error if non-integer value is passed in.
    type=int,

    # Gather all arguments in a list,
    # print an error if no arguments have been passed in.
    nargs="+",
)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Make the list a set, in case of duplicate input.
sales_numbers = set(args.sales_numbers)

for month, value in SALES.items():
    if value in args.sales_numbers:
        print(month)

# Get a set of numbers that were input but not there.
not_found = sales_numbers - set(SALES.values())

for num in not_found:
    print(f"{num} not found")
```

You can now run it and pass in arguments, e.g.:

```
$ my_script.py 123
123 not found
```

```
$ my_script.py 15000
January
```

```
$ my_script.py 21000
July
December
```

```
$ my_script.py 21000 15000
January
July
December
```

```
$ my_script.py 21000 15000 123 9999
January
July
December
123 not found
9999 not found
```

If you forget to pass in the argument(s):

```
$ my_script.py
usage: my_script.py [-h] SALES_NUMBER [SALES_NUMBER ...]
my_script.py: error: the following arguments are required: SALES_NUMBERS
```

When you pass in something that cannot be converted to an integer:

```
$ my_script.py abc
usage: my_script.py [-h] SALES_NUMBER [SALES_NUMBER ...]
my_script.py: error: argument SALES_NUMBER: invalid int value: 'abc'
```

Comes with a handy `--help` argument:

```
$ my_script.py --help
usage: sf_args.py [-h] SALES_NUMBER [SALES_NUMBER ...]

positional arguments:
  SALES_NUMBER

optional arguments:
  -h, --help show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Yes, it does, it's also possible to add sub-commands via [`add_subparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).

Comment: where do description and epilog should go , if they are still valid entries of ArgumentParser()

Comment: You can simply pass the arguments to `ArgumentParser()` on creation:

`parser = ArgumentParser(description="My script that does stuff.", epilog="That's it folks!")`.

It will show up in the help.

Answer (score 0):

ok I was too late as usual but nevertheless here my attempt (worth 10 minutes of revising sys.arg):

```
import sys

sales = {"January": 15000, "February": 22000, "March": 12000, "April": 17000, "May": 81000,
         "June": 13000, "July": 21000, "August": 41200,"September": 25000,
         "October": 21500, "November": 91000, "December": 21000}




search = [int(sys.argv[x]) for x in range(1 , len(sys.argv))]


sales_inv = {v: k for k, v in sales.items()}


for i in search:
    if i in sales.values():

        for key, value in sales.items():
    
            if i == value:   

                print(i,' is : ', key)
    else:
    
        print(i,"not found")
```

it is the same @user696969 but dumbest version, using argparse its cooler